# Is it possible to arrange multiple attribute tables in tabs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, gui

It annoys me that when opening a new attribute table it appears besides old one(s) and even shifts other parts of the GUI around if there is a lack of space.

It would be nice to arrange multiple attribute tables in **tabs** in QGIS. How is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You put the attribute table into a dock widget in settings => options => data sources. Docks can easily be stacked as tabs.

There is still a manual process to it to stack the two tables. As far as I know it's not possible to do this automatically (yet).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I like to see an option to make table stacking in tabs the default behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

[Starting from QGIS 3.14](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-open-attribute-tables-as-tabs), they will open as tabs by default.

> If the option "Open new attribute tables as dock windows" is active,
> new attribute tables will be open as tabs on top of other existing
> attribute tables.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. See also: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6796